# Sigma-algebra & separating measurable from "non-measurable" sets

Tags: measure-theory

In measure theory, I think the idea of specifying a $\sigma$-algebra was to filter out "non-measurable" subsets of the underlying set for which no consistent measure can be defined. And often I've read that members of a $\sigma$-algebra are called measurable sets (relative to a certain measure).

Hence, does there exist a $\sigma$-algebra auch that (for a sensible measure e.g. the Lebesgue one) all its members are indeed truly measurable and all non-members are truly non-measurable? Or, if such a set exists, is it always also a $\sigma$-algebra?

Thx for any insights on this!

Comment: *" I've read that members of a $\sigma $-algebra are called measurable sets (relative to a certain measure)"*. Measurability doesn't depend on a specific measure. Your second question is unclear. What do you mean by "truly measurable" or "truly non-measurable" ? "sensible measure" ?

Comment: I guess certain measures are trivial, such as assigning 0 to every subset, which is consistent with the conditions for a measure. So every subset is "measurable" in this sense. But for the Lebesgue measure, there clearly are contradictions for certain subsets. Can one clearly separate out the non-measurable sets from the measurable ones and is this a sigma-algebra?

Comment: The Lebesgue measurable sets are a clearly defined class and a $\sigma$-algebra, but there are sets outside of it that *could* also be measured, in the sense that there is an extension of the Lebesgue measure that is defined for that set. It's not a clear division at all. In some models of set theory we could even measure **all** subsets of $\Bbb R$ but we lose translation invariance of the extended measure. Lebesgue measure is a compromise: it measures enough sets to be useful and do all analysis we need.

Comment: A possible interpretation of "truly measurable" are the [universally measurable sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_measurable_set), but you're not going to get any reasonable sense of "truly non-measurable" (a candidate of which might be Kharazishvili's [absolutely nonmeasurable sets](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22absolutely+nonmeasurable%22+%22Kharazishvili%22)) for the remaining sets, since your classifications are presumably intended to correspond to (strongly) proper subcollections of the collections of "measurable sets" and "nonmeasurable sets".